# CRichEditCtrl and Arrow Keys

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there a way to capture arrow keys in a derived CRichEditCtrl class?   I request all keys and capture the OnGetCode() and OnChar() commands.

```
UINT MyRichEditCtrl::OnGetDlgCode()
{
   return CRichEditCtrl::OnGetDlgCode() | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
}
```

and

```
void MyRichEditCtrl::OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
   CRichEditCtrl::OnKeyDown(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
   ...    
}
```

And I match them in the message map..

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyRichEditCtrl, CRichEditCtrl)
   ON_WM_CHAR()
   ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I am getting most keys, but no arrow keys.   I get the same result with OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp events as well.     Is there another way to get the arrow keys?

Specifically, I'm interested in knowing if the character at the current cursor position is a parenthesis.  The user can change the cursor position by both typing in a character, clicking somewhere in the edit control with a mouse, or by moving the cursor position with an arrow key.   I'm thinking if I can detect arrow keys, then I can find out if the cursor is at a parenthesis or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code seems wrong. `OnChar` should call `CRichEditCtrl::OnChar`. I guess you do that in your real code.

Anyway, `OnKeyDown` is what you are looking for (arrow keys are not a characters). So, add `ON_WM_KEYDOWN()` to your message map and override `OnKeyDown`. Look for e.g. `VK_LEFT` and `VK_RIGHT`.

But... your approach is wrong. What you need is [CharFromPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfbzb9hb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
CPoint pt = GetCaretPos();
int wordLocation = CharFromPos(pt);
```